# WPF dialog cancel -- a common scenario

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have really difficult time figuring how WPF ComboBox works.  There are many example online but none seem to be going over a very common case, a form with ComboBox and Save/Cancel buttons as described below.

All I am trying to do is to have a WPF form with a single ComboBox in it with 2 strings, say "A" and "B".  And 2 buttons Save and Cancel.

On **Cancel** button click, newly selected value will be ignored.  For example, if when form is opened, ComboBox shows value "A", then when user changes selection to "B" and click Cancel, reopening the form whill show "A".

On **Save** button click, selected value will be saved.  For example, when form was opened, ComboBox shows value "A" and user selects "B" and hits Save, then reopening the form will show "B".

I haven't provided any code because I have none.  I am just trying to find an example / tutorial covering this scenario for my learning.

**UPDATE**
WPF, MVVM (or not, regardless).  All I am looking is a good link covering such a scenario.  All I am finding are minimalistic, just showing combo on form.  Or another version is a) select new value, b) get prompt to confirm you want to select it indeed (needless to say, that is just stupid).
Feels strange for such a common scenario.

Comment: So, are you ok with the part binding data to combobox and selected item? is your question only on the "undoing" the selection unless it is saved? Or is it both?

Comment: MVVM or not? Not don't mind either?

Comment: This site is best suited for more focused questions, like "I'm trying to do **x**, and I'm having this problem **y**" sort of thing.

Comment: @code4life Correct, so imagine my question like "I am trying to learn about using combobox in a form with Cancel / Save operation, and I am having problem finding good online tutorial to cover such scenario".  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you saw a problem here. The only possible biggest problem is probably because you think the control would work like what you imagined it would work (without you doing anything) - you need to put in the **effort** to make it behave like what you need.

Every time you close the form, you are discarding an instance of it. Similarly, when you open the form, you are create a new instance. Since it's a brand new instance, then wouldn't it make sense that it show exactly what it did, just like the first time it was opened?

If you need information to be persistent between closing and opening, then it's as simple as storing it somewhere that does not get destroyed.

For the "save" button's `Click` event handler, copy the value from the combobox to somewhere else, probably a repository, a static singleton somewhere, or mainwindow.

```
// e.g. static singleton
MySingletonStorage.Instance.ComboBoxValue = myComboBox.Text;
```

Then in your form's constructor, simply get the value back from the storage.

```
myComboBox.Text = MySingletonStorage.Instance.ComboBoxValue;
```